# Retrieve the credentials.zip file from GenerateAutonomousDataWarehouseWalletDetails

Tags: oracle-cloud-infrastructure, oci-python-sdk

We are trying to download the wallet credentials.zip file for Autonomous Datawarehouse via Python SDK.

We have an option called `--file` when we do the same operation using oci cli.

`oci db autonomous-data-warehouse generate-wallet --autonomous-data-warehouse-id <ocid> --password <my_admin_password> --file <filename.zip>`

We are trying the same thing using the python sdk, but we do not get an option to download the zip file. We are executing the below code:
`wallet=database_client.generate_autonomous_data_warehouse_wallet("oicd",Password).`

We get a response of 200. 
But how do we download the zip file?
We tried `wallet.data` and `wallet.headers`. Not sure which sub-options to use.

Would be great if someone could help us on this!

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Python SDK API reference](https://oracle-cloud-infrastructure-python-sdk.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/database/client/oci.database.DatabaseClient.html#oci.database.DatabaseClient.generate_autonomous_data_warehouse_wallet) for this operation, this operation returns a "Response object with data of type stream."

So all you need to do is save the response body (wallet.data in your example) to a file with the proper file extension.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
wallet = database_client.generate_autonomous_data_warehouse_wallet(<OCID>, <password>)
with open('<wallet_file>.zip', 'wb') as f:
    for chunk in wallet.data.raw.stream(1024 * 1024, decode_content=False):
        f.write(chunk)
```

The response object (your `wallet`) has a `data` field that needs to be streamed into a zip-file.